# Helm is stuck - status: pending-install

Tags: devops, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy one of my service, but I'm getting the error:

> ##[error]Error: UPGRADE FAILED: another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress

What I have is:

```
development@Azure:~$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.4.0", GitCommit:"7090a89efc8a18f3d8178bf47d2462450349a004", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.14.10"}
development@Azure:~$ helm list -Aa
NAME            NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION
azuredevops     novadevspace    1               2021-04-17 20:32:01.929625514 +0000 UTC pending-install sampleapp-v0.2.0
development@Azure:~$ helm install azuredevops . --debug
install.go:172: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:189: [debug] CHART PATH: /home/development

walk.go:74: found symbolic link in path: /home/development/clouddrive resolves to /usr/csuser/clouddrive

Killed
development@Azure:~$
development@Azure:~$ helm list -Aa
NAME            NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION
azuredevops     novadevspace    1               2021-04-17 20:32:01.929625514 +0000 UTC pending-install sampleapp-v0.2.0
development@Azure:~$
```

For some reason, the process status is "pending-install", and I'm not able to kill it.

Someone can help me to delete it in order to do a new deployment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try `helm rollback`  and then `helm delete releasename`